# How to select a div based on its content in database?

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, backend

[site image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6MMv.jpg)Basically I have a site that pulls up different questions from a database(where different unique ids are assigned to them) and puts them inside different div. I pull question using PHP and put every question in an array. Then i use foreach to print out every question inside different div. I want to show different content for each question when the respective div is clicked.(The content is stored in the same database).How do i know which div is clicked and show the respective content. A javascript solution will be appreciated.

Comment: "How do i know which div is clicked"...if you associate a click event handler with the divs, then `this` inside the the handler's callback function will identify the div. If the div has an ID corresponding to its ID in the database it'll be easy to know which one it is. And then you can use the ID to find the matching other content (which presumably will have the same ID on it somewhere, maybe as a data-attribute), and show it. What have you researched or tried so far yourself? Have you tried to attach click events and see how they work, for example?

Comment: Thanks, I will try again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do whatever you want by examining these codes.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <?php

    $data = [
        'question_1' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'content' => 'content text'
        ],
        'question_2' => [
            'id' => 2,
            'content' => 'content text'
        ]
    ];

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) :
    ?>

        <div data-id="<?= $value['id'] ?>">
            <!-- $value['id'] Or $key -->
        </div>

    <?php
    endforeach;
    ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(() => {
            let element = $('[data-id]');
            element.click((e) => {
                console.log($(e.currentTarget).data('id'));
            })
        })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```